# Ivy used to retrieve guava, now it does not

Tags: ant, guava, ivy

Related question: [Ivy cached a dependency file, but not copy to my lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491229/ivy-cached-a-dependency-file-but-not-copy-to-my-lib)

My situation is nearly identical, except that this has been working for quite a while until recently.

Ivy retrieves other jars: transitive dependencies like com.google.code.findbugs, and specified artifacts like junit.

It does not copy the guava jar to my lib.

ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="mine" module="external-deps"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="14.0.1"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Ant retrieve task:

```
<target name="_ivy_retrieve" depends="init-ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve type="jar" pattern="${lib.dir}/ivy/[conf]/[organisation]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" log="quiet"/>
    <ivy:artifactproperty conf="default" name="lib.[artifact].[type]" value="ivy/[conf]/[organisation]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

Is my ivy.xml specified incorrectly? Is my retrieve task broken? Or, did something break for the 14.0.1 distribution for Guava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Ivy's **type** attribute strongly corresponds to Maven's **packaging** attribute.  Google Guava uses package type **bundle** instead of **jar** which is used by most open source projects.

Ref: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C17.0%7Cbundle

Comment: Thanks. This helped me as well. I changed the type from 'jar' to 'jar,bundle' and now it works.

Comment: Note that this problem relates to [IVY-633](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-633), which was first resolved back in June 2008 for Ivy 2.0, but the resolution is incomplete and ineffective.

Comment: See also my answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491229/ivy-cached-a-dependency-file-but-not-copy-to-my-lib).

Answer (score 2):

The

```
type="jar"
```

attribute was causing the issue. Removing this corrects the problem.

Comment: And there's no need for the "log" attribute as well.