# How can i force intellij + ivy to download what i want it to?

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy

Uinsg IntelliJ, currently ivy gives me this error message:

```
:: downloading artifacts ::
[NOT REQUIRED] folder#scopt;2.10-3.1.0!scopt.jar
```

When I try to use our firm-internal ivy system.

I can see that the jar file is in the correct location that the resolver points to, and the ivy cache (using IntelliJ) is clean.

Ivy otherwise will download files requested.

***The issue is  with IntelliJ, eclipse can find and download the jar with the same ivy.xml and ivy.settings file without any issue***

*This is not a duplicate as suggested - if i change my internal IntelliJ settings to exclude jar files then i get an error at the bottom of the output (stating  that jar files are not to be downloaded). I currently have the logging as "All" in intelliJ)*

~~~~~

The ivy resolver code is:

```
<resolvers>
    <filesystem name="secret-source-resolver" checkmodified="true" checkconsistency="false">
        <artifact pattern="//a/b/c/d/[organisation]/e/f/[module]/[artifact]_[revision].[ext]" />
    </filesystem>
</resolvers>

<modules>
    <module organisation="theOrg" name="scopt" resolver="secret-source-resolver" />
</modules>
```

And the ivy.xml file is

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="theOrg" name="scopt" rev="2.10-3.1.0">
        <artifact name="scopt" type="jar" force="true" conf="runtime" />
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Looking at the folder that i'm getting the files from, the jar files are present.

Finally, in the output:

```
don't use cache for theOrg#scopt;2.10-3.1.0: checkModified=true
 trying //v/campus/ny/cs/theOrg/shared/apps/scopt/scopt_2.10-3.1.0.jar
    tried //v/campus/ny/cs/theOrg/shared/apps/scopt/scopt_2.10-3.1.0.jar
secret-source-resolver: no ivy file found for theOrg#scopt;2.10-3.1.0: using default data
checking theOrg#scopt;2.10-3.1.0[default] from secret-source-resolver against [none]
module revision kept as first found: theOrg#scopt;2.10-3.1.0[default] from secret-source-resolver
found theOrg#scopt;2.10-3.1.0 in secret-source-resolver
```

would indicate that ivy can find it, it just felt that downloading would be... bad?

I am currently using intelliJ 12.0 (company thing, v. hard to upgrade)

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ivy not installing some JARs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218454/ivy-not-installing-some-jars)

Comment: @JanGalinski sadly not, although i wish it was

Comment: @bharal Have you found the solution since then?

Comment: @GáborNagy argh, no i must have done something, but i've left that firm and i have no idea what i did to solve the issue anymore

Answer (score 1):

No solution unfortunately, but we are seeing the same thing.  It does not appear to be consistent however, it works as expected on some developers machines but fails with this error on others.