# Gail Maven - OSGI Bundle as a Dependency - Resolution Issue

Tags: grails, maven, osgi

I am trying to use hector-core as a dependency in a grails maven build.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
  <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-3</version>
  <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

I am getting an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.0.1:maven-compile (default) on project igiveplatform: Failed to create classpath for Grails execution. Encountered problems resolving dependencies of the executable in preparation for its execution. Failure to find me.prettyprint:hector-core:bundle:1.0-3 in http://repo.grails.org/grails/core was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of grails has elapsed or updates are forced

Failed to execute goal on project igiveplatform: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project com.igivefirst:igiveplatform:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
me.prettyprint:hector-core:bundle:1.0-3 in http://repo.grails.org/grails/core 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the 
update interval of grails has elapsed or updates are forced
```

The build is trying to download .bundle file instead of .jar which is in the maven repository.  Grails builds this project normally.

Thanks in advance!

As recommended below I removed the type tag ... another error now

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.0.1:maven-compile (default) on project igiveplatform: Failed to create classpath for Grails execution.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create classpath for Grails execution.
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.generateGrailsExecutionClasspath(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:427)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:225)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:206)
    at org.grails.maven.plugin.MvnCompileMojo.execute(MvnCompileMojo.java:41)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find me.prettyprint:hector-core:bundle:1.0-3 in http://repo.grails.org/grails/core was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of grails has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency type should be jar, not bundle.

(Have a look at a similar question, [Why can't maven find an osgi bundle dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932923/why-cant-maven-find-an-osgi-bundle-dependency))

Comment: That passed one error ... thanks.  Now grails plugin is not happy :(

Comment: @RobertMunteanu I would if the answer fixed my problem. I did the upvote because it helped me partially fix the problem

Comment: Try running maven with a -U setting to force an update; you could also try clearing all hector artefacts out of your maven repository, since they may be in an inconsistent state.