# Maven dependency is downloading only pom not jar for newer version

Tags: java, maven, teiid

I have a dependency on JBoss's teiid framwork. If I add the dependency on older version it downloads the jar file while if I add dependency on newer version it only downloads pom file. below is my pom config

repository:

```
  <repository>
    <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
```

This will download jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.teiid</groupId>
    <artifactId>teiid-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This will download only pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.teiid</groupId>
    <artifactId>teiid-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Update: 
Maven log

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hello-teiid 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/teiid/teiid-client/8.9.1/teiid-client-8.9.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/teiid/teiid-client/8.9.1/teiid-client-8.9.1.pom (2 KB at 1.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-parent/7.4.0.Final-redhat-4/jboss-as-parent-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-parent/7.4.0.Final-redhat-4/jboss-as-parent-7.4.0.Final-redhat-4.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-28T09:41:17-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hello-teiid: Could not resolve dependencies for project hello:hello-teiid:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.teiid:teiid-client:jar:8.9.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.teiid:teiid-client:jar:8.9.1: Could not find artifact org.jboss.as:jboss-as-parent:pom:7.4.0.Final-redhat-4 in jboss-public-repository-group (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: can u share the maven's log?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14913615/1700321.

Comment: Aleksandr, Thanks for the link but I did not get much from the link. Because these dependencies are not getting downloaded in my local repo, so I am getting compilation error in my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for [this artifact in the jboss repo](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~teiid-client), you can see that in [version 8.9.1 its packaging is "bundle"](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/jboss/teiid/teiid-client/8.9.1/teiid-client-8.9.1.pom), while in [version 8.5.0 it was defaulted to "jar"](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/jboss/teiid/teiid-client/8.5.0.Final/teiid-client-8.5.0.Final.pom).

Now that we have noticed this, we can relate to the comment of @AlexandrM, [OSGI Bundle vs jar dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913615/osgi-bundle-vs-jar-dependency),

or to be even more specific, [Why can't maven find an osgi bundle dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932923/why-cant-maven-find-an-osgi-bundle-dependency?lq=1) (note the 2nd answer, not the accepted one. **Basically, you need to add a plugin that defines it, namely the maven-bundle-plugin**).