# Problems with maven apache mina pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, apache-mina

I have following entries in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
    <artifactId>mina-filter-compression</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting  "Missing artifact org.apache.mina:mina-core:bundle:
 2.0.7" error in my pom.xml .

Could someone please help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your pom file:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: please add some description that why would this solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the accepted answer, an explanation why this is necessary:

The various MINA dependencies rely on OSGi bundle artifacts rather than standard JAR files.

As such, it's necessary to add support for these bundle to Maven using the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409602 for a good explanation of OSGi bundles, with links to more info.