# How to create multi module project in maven ? so that all the code base of child projects can be in parent one

Tags: maven

I want to create my project structure as fallows-

my-main-project

|   `-- pom.xml
|
|-- project-B
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |
|   |-- project-B1
|   |`-- pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your `pom.xml`s the usual way. On the inner ones you can add

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>(YOUR GROUP ID)</groupId>
    <artifactId>(YOUR ARTIFACT ID)</artifactId>
    <version>(YOUR VERSION)</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
  </parent>
```

To make them include the outer one.

Comment: But it gives error in parent's pom.xml Project build error: Invalid packaging for parent POM com.samples:mainproject:0.5.022 (/home/workspace/mainproject/pom.xml), must be "pom" but is "war"

Comment: It depends on what you're building. If it's a webapp, specify the packaging on the child POM. Since it's a webapp I reccomend to use `bundle` on the child POM.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389691/what-is-the-meaning-of-type-bundle-in-a-maven-dependency