# Maven - can't find Jackson artifact in central repository although it exists?

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have a `pom.xml` with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
  <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

The dependency exists in Maven's central repo:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/bundle

But when (using Eclipse) i right click on my `pom.xml` file and choose `Run As` -> `Maven install`, it downloads a bunch of dependencies related to that artifact, but finishes with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jackson-json-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.elad:jackson-json-demo:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:bundle:2.9.6 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I tried a couple of other versions and also deleting the dependency from my local repo and trying again, but it didn't help. What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Are there issues with other dependencies too or just this one?

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy, and i will try another dependency and update the post.

Comment: @kutschkem - no issues with other dependencies.

Comment: @Gambit2007 I saw some post regarding same :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389691/what-is-the-meaning-of-type-bundle-in-a-maven-dependency#:~:text=The%20plugin%20treats%20all%20the,to%20bundle%20into%20a%20jar.

Remove type and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have *never* heard of an artifact type `bundle`. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html)'s a list of *some* of the valid artifact `type` strings.

Just remove the `<type />` tag from your dependency block and it will default to `jar`.

Comment: That was it, thank you!! I'm surprised that it was included in the dependency snippet on the maven repo..

Comment: @Gambit2007 That might have been a typo in the docs! :) The following link, for example, also works: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/nonsense