# org.json.* is not accessible in JAVA Maven Project as a dependency

Tags: java, json, maven

I am making a JavaFX project (for the GUI) on Maven and for the moment I want to convert a StringBuffer object to JSON.

I tried to add the dependency org.json from Maven but there is a problem in pom.xml file
`Missing Artifact org.json:json:bundle:20220924`

I tried adding an older version of org.json dependency, it had the same issue

I tried a different dependency, everything was ok in the pom.xml file but I could not import it into my project (any dependency).

All dependencies return this error: `The type org.json.JSONArray is not accessible`

Lastly, I tried to download the json-java.jar from github and add it into a libs folder on the base project directory and added it in the pom file as a dependency but it could not be resolved either.

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>books</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/json-20220924.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the end I downloaded Maven again and extracted it into a folder and changed my environment variables on path. Maven is successfully installed on version 3.8.7

Thank you in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**

I should mention that I tried it on a new java project (without maven) and it works fine, by importing the .jar file from git-hub repository

Comment: Remove `<type>bundle</type>` and try again. See [What is the meaning of type "bundle" in a maven dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5389691/3124333) for more info.

Comment: I did that and there were no errors on pom but I still could not reference it in my code. I get this error: `The type org.json.JSONArray is not accessible`